# The equivalent of least squares, but for vectors

Tags: reference-request, numerical-methods, vectors, least-squares

Given a set of poins, one can use a fitting method such as least squares to find the straight (or the parabola, or the 3rd grade equivalent) that's closest to all points at the same time (via minimizing the *distance*).

My question is: given a set of information about some vectors (such as position, magnitude and direction), **Is there a way of finding a vector function that behaves similar to the given vectors?** This question arises by trying to measure vorticity in the results of a given monte carlo simulation.

Comment: The method of minimizing the least squares error to find the best fitting values is broadly applicable. So the answer must be: YES. The question you must answer is in what sense the vectorial nature of the quantities involved is essential. What if you treat the components of the vectors as independent scalar quantities?

Comment: That's a nice approach, going component by component.